# Deleting multiple time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-cleaning

I am trying do delete multiple time intervals from the dataset. I have separate data for time intervals and I have dataset that I am trying do clean.

```
drop_time.head()
Out[14]: 
                Start                 End
0 2019-01-28 19:50:00 2019-01-28 23:00:00
1 2019-03-12 00:40:00 2019-03-12 12:40:00
2 2019-03-12 16:20:00 2019-03-12 18:40:00
3 2019-04-12 15:30:00 2019-04-12 17:40:00
4 2019-05-12 07:40:00 2019-05-12 13:40:00
```

```
#Drop Dates
drop_time = pd.read_excel('Time_line.xlsx')

drop_start = drop_time['Start']
drop_end = drop_time['End']

index = 0
while index <= len(drop_start)-1:
    df_droped = df_clean.drop[(df_clean['Time'] > pd.Timestamp(drop_start.loc[index][0])) & 
                      (df_clean['Time'] < pd.Timestamp(drop_end.loc[index][0]))]
```

When I execute it I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-49cc734f7209>", line 8, in <module>
    df_droped = df_clean.drop[(df_clean['Time'] > pd.Timestamp(drop_start.loc[index][0])) &

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What is the smallest time increment from the original data? It might be faster to build an index of all unwanted timestamps and drop them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be from this portion
`pd.Timestamp(drop_start.loc[index][0]))`
of your code (it's difficult to tell). But with this, are you trying to get an element or its index?